# Magic box game C#

Tags: c#, console

This is an example that we took about building a magic box game in Console app, it supposed to take the size from the user, then produce a matrix of the size that the user has enterd, filled with the numbers starting with 1 to the size acoording to this role:

- first number(1) should be written at the first row, in the middle col
- then we will check if the recently entered num % size not equal to 0;then we will minmize the row, col and put the second number
- if (num% size ==0) row++

Example output screen of size 3:

[image]

```
Console.Clear();
int number;

do
{
    Console.Write("Please Enter Odd Number :");
    number=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
} while (number % 2 == 0);

Console.Clear();
Console.SetCursorPosition(25, 3);

int col = 0;
int row = 1;
double x = (number / 2) + 1;
col = (int)x;

Console.SetCursorPosition(col*3 + 25, row + 3);
Console.Write(1);

for (int i = 1; i < number*number; i++)
{
    if (i % number != 0)
    {
        if (col==1)
        {
            col = number;
        }
        else
        {
            col--;
        }

        if (row == 1)
        {
            row = number;
        }
        else
        {
            row--;
        }

        Console.SetCursorPosition(col*3 + 25, row+3);
        Console.Write(i+1); 
    }
    else if (i % number == 0)
    {
        if (row == number)
        {
            row = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            row++;
        }

        Console.SetCursorPosition(col *3+ 25, row + 3);
        Console.Write(i+1); 
    }
}

Console.SetCursorPosition(27, 27);
```

What i really don’t understand is when we set the position, why it multiple col times 3+ 25?!

Comment: It's difficult to understand your requirements, and just as difficult to understand what your actual question is

Comment: Probably because `col*3 + 25` appears several times throughout the code. Is this somebody else's code and you're asking why it's written as it is? I'm also struggling to understand the question.

Comment: yes it’s somebody else’s code, i want to know how does the formating code work to run the output at this position in the pic?

Comment: Positions throughout your code have 25... so i guess that 25 is the 'start' position of where the matrix table is drawn on the screen.

Comment: i think that so but i don’t get why it use multiple in col set position, and why sum in row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite easy:

the `+25` is a static offset to position the matrix in the middle of the screen. If you would try to produce larger matrices (e.g. 10 x 10) you would see on your screen that the matrix is not centered.

the `col * 3` just preserved a place of three characters for each number. Meaning your numbers should not getting greater than 99 or you couldn't distinguish two numbers showing up side by side.

Answer (score 0):

I think that centralises the output display leaving gaps between columns

Comment: Because col+3 just shifts all columns over by 3, while col*3 shifts each column by a slightly different amount, leaving space between columns. Try it with different values and see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing out values of your variables to check when and why they change their values. It usually helps.

Answer (score -1):

This is because you want to write the matrix on a certain location the screen.

This: `Console.SetCursorPosition(col*3 + 25, row + 3);`

Will put the first element on:

```
x = 1*3 + 25 = 28
y = 1 + 3 = 4
```

The next at:

```
x = 2*3 + 25 = 28
y = 1 + 3 = 4
```

The *3 will create a 'tab' and the + 25 will translate it.

Comment: I'm curious about the -1. Explane yourself please?